# gcc on OS X leads to dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libffi.6.dylib

Tags: macos, gcc, llvm, libffi

```
$ gcc t0.c
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/libexec/llvm-9.0/lib/libLLVM.dylib
  Reason: image not found
fatal error: /opt/local/bin/as: fatal error in /opt/local/bin/clang-mp-9.0

$ gcc --version
gcc (MacPorts gcc9 9.2.0_1) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you on an apple silicon Mac?

Comment: Yes.___________

Comment: That’s likely the problem. Ensure you flip your shell/env to the correct architecture for what you are building and linking against

Comment: I don't understand. I am on OS X, compiling a simple C program  for OS X from the terminal.

Comment: right. it looks like your version of gcc is compiled for intel processors, not for arm/apple silicon. you'll have to load an intel environment and shell to get the right dynamic libraries pointed at it.

Comment: Then, I misunderstood your "apple silicon Mac". The OS X I use is running on Intel CPU. Previously I could compile `t0.c` just fine, but now there is a `Library not loaded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it was fixed:

```
# update ports tree
$ sudo port selfupdate

# uninstall all ports
# note: in my case uninstalling all ports is much faster than
#       auto-rebuilding ports which have/cause linking issues
$ sudo port -fp uninstall installed

# install needed ports
$ port install xxx yyy zzz

# test
$ gcc t0.c
<no errors as expected>
```

More info: https://guide.macports.org/#using.common-tasks.